# Timepicker from android developers not static allowed

Tags: android, android-activity, timepicker

I took the original TimePicker-Source from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

and paste it in a new class in Android Studio. Android Studio throws an error "Modifier 'static' not allowed here". What's wrong? Here's the source:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

And btw: is there an easy way to use a timepicker in an activity? Nearly all examples here work with "showDialog()", which is depricated.

Comment: Java basics... Google for: when should we use static for java classes

Answer (score 9):

The supplied sample was implicitly assuming that you were adding that code inside of another `Activity` or `Fragment` as an internal class. If that's not what you're doing, remove the `static` from it. Note though that communicating between `DialogFragment` when it's in an external class gets a bit tiresome (you'll have to use an interface to communicate back and forth).

Regarding your second question, to show the dialog use something like:

```
DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to paste the above content parallel to the activity class deceleration, actually the above code should be an inner class.

```
public class NewCaseEntry extends AppCompatActivity {}
public static class TimePickerFragment extends ... {}
```

This is wrong, it should be

```
public class NewCaseEntry extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static class TimePickerFragment extends ... {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thanks to Kasra!

I also found out, that you have to put it in a dialog-fragment. But these are from API 11 and up (mine will support from API 5).
It's possible to use them by installing the compatibility-pack in Android Studio. So I wait for deprication, maybe in API 20 my App has become obsolete :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be used as an inner class with the **static** word as below:

```
public class yourclassname extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_input );
}

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

}

If you want to make it as a separate class you can use it without the **static** word as below:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```